# Stop alert desable option in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form something like this:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" >
    <input type="text" id="mytext" name="mytext" />
    <input name="submit" id="btnValidate" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

And I have a Jquery for it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#btnValidate').click(function() {
        if($("#btnValidate").val()==""){
            alert('All fields are mandatory');
            return false;       
        }   
    });
});
</script>
```

But when second time comes this alert, that show an another checkbox with a dialog like *prevent this page from creating additional dialogs* and this option can disable my alert. I want to stop this option. I want if I submit an empty field, every time alert will be come.

And secondly, I want to a cancel button on that alert, If I press that cancel button, then form will be submitted with empty input.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. It's a browser feature

You can, however, look into modal popups like jQuery UI Dialog or Why not use the html require attribute, you can use this to prevent people from submitting the form. They don't use the default alert() function and therefore, bypass the issue you're running into completely.

---

Check out this link: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: @@Torean.. Yes, required attribute is working. Thank you.. But I want to show my own custom dialog. How can I do this? If you don't mind, may I have more help to do this? I don't know what kind of jquery or else I can use...

Comment: without me giving the answer to you but actually just helping you out on the correct route, i would say check out this - http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Simple-Custom-Dialog-Popup-Plugin-With-jQuery.html, they have examples plus code to put you on the right path, you will get it. if not then let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Alerts are designed to block the tab or window. This stops all javascript from running on that page and waits for the user to respond. Its a hangover from the old days, it had to block the page or the code would continue on befor the user had responded.
We all wish that they would disappear, but as long as people keep making sites that use them we have to put up with them. So People who make browsers added the "stop alerts from this page"  check box to discourage site creators from using them and using them to manipulate the client's browser by blocking navigation.

There is nothing you can do to block that option. The best thing to do is get user input via a different method. There are lots of alerts, prompts, confirmation dialogs that are written in javascript and HTML. They do not block the page and they can not be removed from your site if you dont want. Look in Github or try out JQuery they have zillions.

And please forget you even knew they ever existed.